# Plone External methods help

Tags: python, plone, zope

I'm having trouble getting a simple external methods in plone working correctly.
In my extensions folder I have a python script named blast_query.py code below:

```
def print_query(self, x):
    print(x)
```

my external methods looks like:

> Id: run_blast_query
>
> Title:
>
> Module Name: blast_query
>
> Function Name: print_query

My python script in the ZMI looks like:

```
#Import a standard function, and get the HTML request and response objects.
from Products.PythonScripts.standard import html_quote
request = container.REQUEST
RESPONSE = request.RESPONSE

# Insert data that was passed from the form
query=request.query

context.print_query(context,query)
```

I just want to pass the query from the form to the function so i know i have it working correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should call your external method by id:

```
context.run_blast_query(context,query)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your understanding of python methods.

I would expect:

```
context.print_query(context,query)
```

to return:

```
TypeError: print_query() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Remember, in python, *obj.method()* implicitly passes *obj* as the first parameter of *method()*

Answer (score 0):

"request" is available from "self".

use self.REQUEST inside your external method.

No extra parameter needed.